# Init, Init with arguments and Convenience Init

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, init

When to use init, init with arguments or convenience init in iOS 8 (Swift),

What is the equivalent of convenience init in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class will have a required initialiser, and convenience initialisers will call the required initialiser.

In Objective-C you have designated initialisers, and all other initialisers called this initialiser.